# How to create selector like jQuery with additional functions?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand  how to work jQuery and other libraries. I would like to know how to create a selector with this format:

```
$("#selector").get();
```

By the moment, I am trying the next, but i don't know how to run internal functions (get(), set()):

```
var $ = (function() {

    var jQuery = {
        get: function() {
            console.log("get() function!!");
            return this;
        },
        set: function() {
            console.log("set() function!!");
            return this;
        }
    };

    return function(el) {
        return document.querySelector(el);
    }       
})();
```

I have read something about modular pattern design in JavaScript, but I don't understand all.

Comment: Modify `jQuery.fn`, an alias for the prototype

Comment: And if you want to add multiple functions, you can use `$.fn.extend($.fn, {...})`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not writting a jQuery plugin, I'm trying to write a "library" and learn.

Comment: Read the source ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to make chainable functions, is to first and foremost create instances with the `new` keyword.

This can be done "automatically" by making sure the `this` value of the called function is an instance of itself, if not explicitly call it with `new`.

Then it's just a matter of returning the instance and using prototyped methods.

```js
var $ = function(selector) {
  if (! (this instanceof $) ) {
    return new $(selector);
  }
  this.el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return this;
}

$.prototype.css = function(prop, val) {
  this.el.forEach(function(element) {
    element.style[prop] = val;
  });

  return this;
}

$('#test').css('color', 'red').css('font-size', '30px')
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

Comment: Remember that jQuery does a lot more things than simply `document.querySelectorAll(selector);`. It activelly avoids it for ids (recurring to `document.getElementById();`) and, with some care, for tags too (using `document.getElementsByTagName();`). Not to mention all the pseudo-selectors.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - of course it does, jQuery is 250 000 bytes *(not minimized)*, so it does a whole lot of things *(...all things)*. This answer is just to show how chainable methods work, not how the entire jQuery library works.

Comment: Yes, but the comment is just to tell to curious readers that jQuery isn't just simply using `document.querySelectorAll(selector);` with a bunch gimmicks on top.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - no, for the "curious reader", it does [**this**](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=init), unfortunately copying the entire `init` code of jQuery doesn't make for a very good answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, but jQuery uses a colon instead of a comma in the css prototype. Like $('.element').css({background: 'red'});

Comment: @codeWithMe - no it does not! When you write it like I did above, there's no colon. You can either pass in two arguments, seperated by a comma, as in my answer, or you pass in an object, as in your comment, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const $ = function(selector) {
    if (!(this instanceof $)) {
        return new $(selector);
    };
    this.el = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
};
$.prototype.css = function(obj) {
    this.el.forEach(function(element) {
        element.style[Object.keys(obj)[0]] = Object.values(obj);
    });
};
$.prototype.click = function(callback) {
    this.el.forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', callback, false);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `this` or `$(selector)` is array like `[div, div]` not object `{el: [div, div]}`, so its not using `this.el` to modified the elements,  here simplified version

```js
if (window.$ === undefined) window.$ = (function () {
    var $, fun = {}, emptyArray = [];

    function Z(dom, selector) {
        var i, len = dom ? dom.length : 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) this[i] = dom[i];
        this.length = len;
        this.selector = selector || '';
    }
    fun.Z = function (dom, selector) {return new Z(dom, selector);};
    fun.init = function (selector, context) {
        if (!selector) return fun.Z();
        var dom = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        return fun.Z(dom, selector);
    };
    Z.prototype = {
        splice: emptyArray.splice,
        forEach: emptyArray.forEach,
        html: function (str) {
            return this.forEach(function (el) {
                el.innerHTML = str;
            });
        },
        css: function(obj, value){
          if(typeof obj == 'object'){ // like: .css({background: 'red'})
             for(var k in obj){
              return this.forEach(function (el) {
                el.style[k] = obj[k];
              });
            }
          }
          else{ // called: .css('background', 'red')
            return this.forEach(function (el) {
                el.style[obj] = value;
              });
          }
        }
    };
    $ = function (sel, ctx) {return fun.init(sel, ctx); };

    return $;
})();
```

```html
<div class="test"> AAAA </div>
<div class="test"> BBBB </div>

<button onclick="$('.test').css({background: 'red'})">red</button>
<button onclick="$('.test').css('background', 'blue')">blue</button>
<br />
<button onclick="console.log($('.test'))">log to console</button>
```